# Is there a way to know if user did rate my app iOS

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, rate

I have a feature that suggest a rating view to the user. 
 If the user say YES he is redirected to the AppStore on my App page. 
 Is there a way to know if he really made a rating after coming back to use my App?

Comment: there is no way for that

Comment: No, there is no way to check if the user rated your app.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to do this because I found an app (https://waterllama.com) that does it and I'm wondering how